# Slick Slider Navigation showing less items than supposed to at some breakpoint

Tags: css, slick.js

I've built a slick slider with custom navigation.

```js
(function ($) {
   
    $('.slider-for').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      arrows: false,
      fade: true,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
      asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
      dots: false,
      customPaging: function(slick,index) {
        return '<a>'+'</a>';
     },

      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            arrows: false,
            dots: true,
          }
        }
        
        // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
        // settings: "unslick"
        // instead of a settings object
      ]

    });
    $('.slider-nav').slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 5,
      asNavFor: '.slider-for',
      focusOnSelect: true,
      dots: false,
      customPaging: function(slick,index) {
        return '<a>' + (index + 1) + '</a>';
     },

      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            centerMode: false,
            arrows: false,
            dots: false,
          }
        }
        
        // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
        // settings: "unslick"
        // instead of a settings object
      ]

      

    });

    
  
  })(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700");
body {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

#main-slider-wrap {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}
#main-slider-wrap .container {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #main-slider-wrap .container {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
}
#main-slider-wrap .slick-slide {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
#main-slider-wrap .slick-slide.slick-current {
  opacity: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #main-slider-wrap .slide-item {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
#main-slider-wrap .slide-item.slick-center {
  opacity: 1;
}
#main-slider-wrap .slide-item img {
  width: auto;
  height: 44px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #main-slider-wrap .slide-item img {
    height: 54px;
  }
}
#main-slider-wrap .slick-dots {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
  #main-slider-wrap .slick-dots {
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
}
#main-slider-wrap .slick-dots li {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 18px;
  height: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#main-slider-wrap .slick-dots li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
#main-slider-wrap .slick-dots li.slick-active a {
  background-color: #7AE1BF;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #main-slider-wrap .slick-dots li.slick-active {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}
#main-slider-wrap .slick-dots li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #001D3A;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 12px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#main-slider-wrap .slick-dots li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#main-slider-wrap .slider-for .text-center a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
#main-slider-wrap .slider-for h3 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: -0.15px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  height: 81px;
  min-height: 81px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #main-slider-wrap .slider-for h3 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: auto;
  }
}
#main-slider-wrap .slider-for a {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FF8672;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#main-slider-wrap .slider-for a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#main-slider-wrap .slider-nav .slick-current h3 {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #00DDBD;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://13779usreg20181102.com/us/sites/all/themes/krm/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
         <div id="main-slider-wrap">
           <div class="center">
            <div class="slider-nav text-center">
              <div class="slide-item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0046/8893/7030/files/DailyMail_logo_desktop.png?6710">

              </div>
              <div class="slide-item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0046/8893/7030/files/JCK_logo_desktop.png?6710">
              </div>
              <div class="slide-item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0046/8893/7030/files/NationalJeweler_logo_desktop.png?6710">

              </div>
              <div class="slide-item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0046/8893/7030/files/DigitalCommerce_logo_desktop.png?6710">
              </div>
              <div class="slide-item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0046/8893/7030/files/DPA_logo_desktop.png?6710">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
           <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2">
                <div class="slider-for">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <h3>They're real and they're spectacular!</h3>
                    <a href="https://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-6655049/The-company-cracked-code-harnessing-light-diamonds-invisible-cuts.html" target="_blank">Read article</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <h3>A New Diamond Brand Helmed by Former Apple & Sleep Number Bed Execs</h3>
                    <a href="https://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-6655049/The-company-cracked-code-harnessing-light-diamonds-invisible-cuts.html" target="_blank">Read article</a>

                  </div>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <h3>Forget the 4 C’s. Meet the 3 S’s.</h3>
                    <a href="https://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-6655049/The-company-cracked-code-harnessing-light-diamonds-invisible-cuts.html" target="_blank">Read article</a>

                  </div>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <h3>Diamond startup targets millennials with sparkly diamonds.</h3>
                    <a href="https://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-6655049/The-company-cracked-code-harnessing-light-diamonds-invisible-cuts.html" target="_blank">Read article</a>

                  </div>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <h3>Sparkle Cut CEO interview.</h3>
                    <a href="https://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-6655049/The-company-cracked-code-harnessing-light-diamonds-invisible-cuts.html" target="_blank">Read article</a>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At 1024, I have it so it only shows one.

For some reason at certain breakpoints, the top slider (slider-nav) shows less than 5 items? Not sure why it's happening? Any CSS issues? Thanks in advance!

this one only showing 4 items
[image: only showing 4 items]

this only is only showing 2
[image: only showing 2 items]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you are using the slick slider in a way it was intended to work.

My previous option didn't work so I rolled back to this answer.

The slides aren't missing, they are hidden by the slick slider script with a css transform inline style on slick-track container.

Perhaps is there a function to disable sliding effect for wide screens as it is what make your slides hidding.

Otherwise, you should be able to overwrite it with css:

```
.slick-slider .slick-track, .slick-slider .slick-list {
     -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
      -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
      -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
      -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

This code was already in `primary.css` sheet but I added the !important as it couldn't take control on element style.

This code should be placed in a media query for targeted screen sizes because the translate3d is used to slide elements in mobile view (1 by 1 element).

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php if (count($images) < 5) { 
    echo " .my-gallery.slider-nav.slick-vertical.slick-initialized.slick-slider .slick-list .slick-track{ -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)!important; }"; 
}?>
```

here, I try something this, I know it's not permanent solution but it's perfectly work for me for whatever I want to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.